# Proposition $4.16$ from Ballmann's Lectures on Kähler Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm reading proposition 4.16 from Ballmann's [Lectures on Kähler Manifolds](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf.):

> Let $M$ be a complex manifold with a compatible Riemann metric $g$ and Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, then:
>   $$d\omega(X,Y,Z)=g((\nabla_XJ)Y,Z)+g((\nabla_YJ)Z,X)+g((\nabla_ZJ)X,Y)$$
>   $$2g((\nabla_XJ)Y,Z)=d\omega(X,Y,Z)-d\omega(X,JY,JZ)$$

He begins the proof by saying "Since $M$ is a complex manifold, we can assume that the vector fields $X,Y,Z,JY$ and $JZ$ commute".

I assume "X,Y commutes" (two variables) means $[X,Y]=0$, but I don't understand what it has to do with $M$ being complex and what does he mean by "$X,Y,Z,JY,JZ$ commute" (five variables).

Comment: Is it saying we can find $n$ vector fields $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ such that $[X_l,X_m]=0$ and any vector field is of the form $\sum_{l=1}^n f_l X_l$ with $f_l:M \to \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @reuns I guess that makes sense. But using your construction, can we conclude $[X,JY] =[X,JZ]=...=0$? I guess that's what he does, since all the brackets vanish in his calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equalities you have to prove are of the form $T(X,Y,Z)=0$, where $T$ is a tensor. A tensor something which satisfies $T(a X+bX', Y,Z)=aT(X, Y, Z)+bT(X',T,Z)$ for $a,b$ to functions (and similarly for, $Y,Z$).

Then, you choose a complex chart $(z_1,..., z_n)$, and you check it for the fields $\partial \over {\partial z_i} $, ${\partial \over {\partial z_i }} = i {\partial \over {\partial z_i}}$. This is enough, because these fields generate all vector fields.

Note that these fields  **commute**, and furthermore  that $i {\partial \over {\partial z_i}}$ is the local expression for $J\partial \over {\partial z_i} $. So to prove that $T(X,Y,Z)=0$ it is enough to check it for all fields $X,Y,Z$ such that $X,Y,Z, JX,JY,JZ$ commute

Comment: I'm confused because $J$ is a function from $TM$ to itself, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}_j}\in TM\otimes \mathbb{C}$, so what does $J\frac{\partial }{\partial z_j}$ mean?

Comment: Also, what does $\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial z_j},\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}_j}\right]$ mean since $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is defined for elements in $TM$?

Comment: $J_x$ at some point $x$ is an element of $End(T_x(M))$. By abuse of notation, one sometimes denotes also by $J$ its complexification, which is a complex endomorphism of $T_x(M) \otimes \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Similarly, one can consider the Lie bracket of two smooth complex vector fields, by just complexifying the usual (real) Lie bracket.